# Are these line codes the same in golang?

Tags: go, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is A same as B?

A

```
if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&t); err != nil {
    rnd.JSON(w, http.StatusProcessing, err)
    return
}
```

B

```
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&t);
if err != nil {
    rnd.JSON(w, http.StatusProcessing, err)
    return
}
```

Comment: They are the same, yes.

Comment: Do note that in A example the `err` variable will only be accessible inside if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent except one difference: the scope of the `err` variable. In the A version the scope of the `err` variable is the `if` statement: it's not accessible after the `if`.

In the B version the `err` variable will be in scope after the `if` statement too, and if `err` is already defined earlier, it could result in a compile-time error too.

It's good practice to always minimize the scope of variables (which gives you less chance to misuse them). If you do not wish to further examine the returned error after the `if`, it's better to use the A version. If you do need it after the `if`, then obviously the B version is the way to go.

Comment: Variables declared in the if statement are also available in the else-block

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Yes, the `else` branch is part of the `if` statement.